# Why does Obi-wan tell Anakin not to jump?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, obi-wan-kenobi

In the last battle of Episode 3, Obi-wan tells Anakin not to try jumping at him. Why does he do this? If Anakin surrenders, Obi-wan can't take him into custody and put him on trial, since the Republic has fallen. I wondered if Obi-wan was actually trying to goad Anakin into making that ill-advised jump, but he seems sincere when he says "don't try it". What does Obi-wan want Anakin to do at this point?

Comment: Kenobi tells him not to jump because he can see that if he tries it, it'll give him an opening for a killing strike against Anakin

Comment: Well that's a vote for "goading him into making that ill-advised jump" but I don't know, the tone is more pleading than taunting the way I see it.

Comment: Obi-Wan has the tactical advantage: the outcome of the battle is clear. Maybe he'd rather Anakin let him go and be carved into pieces by Palpatine as punishment instead of doing it himself?

Comment: @davidgalbraith - You misunderstand me. Kenobi is begging Anakin not to put him in a position where he's forced to kill him. He'd like Anakin to surrender so that they can both oppose Palatine.

Comment: a definite dupe but cant find it. went through this particular scene so many, many, many times. I'm still soooo surprised when another question about this pops up. Anakin loves his pupil. Doesn't want to kill him as he has the high ground and no mater what Anakin does he has lost. It is Star Wars own Kobiashi maru scenario. Anakin is too arrogant to realize that he is beat and tries anyway. Overconfidence of the dark side.

Comment: @Cherubel I'm sure you mean "**Obi-wan** loves his pupil".

Comment: I've always questioned this scene, but for a different reason: I never bought that Anakin's jump was doomed to fail when Obi-wan himself pulled off a similar jump to defeat Darth Maul. Sure, Obi-wan had a shorter jump and (perhaps) the element of surprise, but Anakin had surer footing (standing instead of dangling) and more raw power. Or to look at it another way: if Yoda had been in Anakin's place, he could have made the leap and cut Obi-wan into a dozen pieces before landing and no one would have thought "but Obi-wan had the high ground!"

Comment: @Josh I read a plausible explanation of this once: that Obi-wan developed special techniques for defending the high ground after seeing how it exposed Maul to a jumping attack like that.

Comment: @Josh We could hand wave this away as some kind of Force premonition/clairvoyance in both cases. Unsatisfying, but at least has some measure of consistency.

Comment: @krillgar you got me wondering, was Anakin Obi-wan's first (and only) pupil?

Comment: Because he underestimates Anakin's power.

Comment: @Celeritas: First?  Probably, since he inherited the task from Qui-Gon.  Only?  Certainly not, are you forgetting about Luke?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1. He actually likes Anakin and doesn't want to kill him.
2. A Jedi that is not fueled by hate would not make that jump since it's obviously a bad idea, whereas a Sith lets his rage guide him into making that jump.
   If he would have surrendered I guess Obi-wan would have given him another chance to come to the light side, so with 1. he hopes that that's the outcome.

Hope that's kinda understandable.

Comment: If it's obviously a bad idea, why would a Sith do it?

Comment: @CHEESE: Overconfidence.

Comment: And Contempt. While Obi-Wan was warning Anakin to not do it because he didn't want to harm Anakin, Anakin's contempt for the Jedi made it so that Obi-Wan's words made Ani think Obi was trying to save himself, rather than being generous

Comment: @CHEESE Anger clouds one's judgement

Comment: Interesting! I had always thought Obi-wan had totally given up on Anakin prior to this and was just on Mustafar to kill him like he'd gone to Utapau to kill Grievous. Tough to recover from killing Younglings. But I can see him holding out a small sliver of deluded hope of turning Anakin light again, that he only finally gives up on when Anakin makes this jump.

Comment: @CHEESE: Anger is a potent, positive toolkit in the human arsenal that gives us a great deal of strength, and can allow us to think more rationally under extreme stress. However, if it's not properly tempered by wisdom and experience, it can be (and often is) taken too far. Anakin was already in a delicate condition because of a combination of his innate, passionate personality and his tragic background, and the constant use of Force powers to amplify the rage drove him way over an edge he wasn't experienced enough to see, let alone avoid. His condition is where we get the term "mad with rage"

Comment: @MichaelS "mad with rage" is also known as "Sith."

Comment: @CHEESE: Not really. The Sith could never get anywhere if they couldn't keep a level head. The Sith way is for individuals to feed their passions as a means of strength, through which they can achieve their goals, which is in stark contrast to the Jedi method of suppressing their emotions to be guided by a colder logic. But Sith aren't inherently out of control, or evil; just different. In-universe, it seems the Sith method is harder to control than the Jedi method, but clearly many Sith (such as Palpatine, or original trilogy Darth Vader) have managed to do so.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the in-universe factual explanation, there is also the metaphorical necessity. In that scene, Obi-Wan temporarily got the "high ground", an important tactical advantage for fencing. By showing a reluctance to kill Anakin, and offering him a chance at redemption, Obi-Wan takes the **moral** high ground as well. Obi-Wan is the last white knight; he *must* be gallant to the last.

One may argue that being a jedi knight implies such poses. Possibly, Obi-Wan feels compelled by the Force to do so; not offering that last chance to Anakin would constitute a step in the direction of the dark side. But, also, this over-the-top display of chivalry is constitutive to the story as a whole; it makes it worth telling.

In that sense, it is similar to the business between Luke, Vader and the Emperor at the end of Episode VI: while they were sword-fighting, the murder-bears were mincing through the imperial troops, and the second Dark Star would have been destroyed regardless of whether Luke had won or had succumbed to the dark side. But in the Star Wars universe, everything happens both factually and spiritually. This is a fundamental principle of how things work in that far, far away galaxy. Without this mirroring between metaphors and tangible events, Star Wars would be a mere accumulation of peripeties; it would look like a Star Trek episode (with a bigger budget).